# join rows in CSV with different sized sections python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a csv file structered like this:

```
|     publish_date     |sentence_number|character_count|    sentence       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1           |               |               |                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |      -1       |       0       | Sentence 1 here.  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |       0       |      14       | Sentence 2 here.  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |       1       |      28       | "Sentence 3 here. |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |       2       |      42       | Sentence 4 here." |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |       3       |      56       | Sentence 5 here.  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         end          |               |               |                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          2           |               |               |                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |      -1       |       0       | Sentence 1 here.  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02/01/2012  00:12:00 |       0       |      14       | Sentence 2 here.  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         end          |               |               |                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         end          |               |               |                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'd like to do is combine each block of sentences into paragraphs to output individual paragraphs:

```
["Sentence 1 here.", "Sentence 2 here.", ""Sentence 3 here.", "Sentence 4 here."", "Sentence 5 here."]
```

Some sentences are quotes which continue into a new sentence, whilst others are entirely embedded within a sentence.

So far I've got this:

```
def read_file():

    file = open('test.csv', "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    included_cols = [3]

    for row in reader:
        content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)

        print content    
    return content

read_file()
```

But this just outputs a list of sentences like so:

```
['Sentence 1 here.']
['Sentence 2 here.']
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the fourth element from each row, you are creating a list of each fourth element:

```
def read_file():
    file = open('test.csv', "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    return [row[3] for row in reader if len(row) > 3 and row[3]]
```

Should output:

```
['sentence', 'Sentence 1 here.', 'Sentence 2 here.', ' "Sentence 3 here.', ' Sentence 4 here."', ' Sentence 5 here.', 'Sentence 1 here.', 'Sentence 2 here.']
```

If you want the paras split into sections:

```
from itertools import groupby
def read_file():
    file = open('temp.txt', "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    paras = (row[3] for row in reader if len(row) > 3)
    return [list(v) for k, v in groupby(paras,key=lambda x: x != "") if k]
```

Groupby should output something like:

```
[['sentence', 'Sentence 1 here.', 'Sentence 2 here.', 
 ' "Sentence 3 here.', ' Sentence 4 here."', ' Sentence 5 here.'],
 ['Sentence 1 here.', 'Sentence 2 here.']]
```

Comment: It looks like it's almost there but now it's throwing a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @sammy88888888, try the edit,  your csv is comma delimited yes?

Comment: Yeah it's comma delimited. That's pretty much done it, thanks! Only anomoly is that some sentence are broken up with this: `', '` and others like this: `', "`. Any idea why or whether it matters?

Comment: Actually the issue is because you have some quoted strings, I would not worry about it, if you need to you can str.strip the whitespace.